# Orchard CMS giving Sql Server Errors when trying to update anything

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, orchardcms

I have taken a live Orchard website and put it on a dev machine.
The database is running on Sql Server 2008r2.

Logging in and retrieving from the database works as expected but when I try to edit anything (Email settings, content part) I get the following SQL error:-

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

There are no errors in the Orchard log file.

Named Pipes and TCP/IP are enabled on SQL Server. What could be causing this?

Comment: Firewall (at either end) perhaps?

Comment: I have disabled the firewall but this doesn't seem to help unfortunately.

Comment: login used in the connection string or by the asp.net process doesn't have write permissions on the db?